# Issues traversing views in Ionic and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I'm having a hard time understanding how different views are handled in Ionic and Angular. I have the following code:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

    .state('index', {
      url: "/",
      templateURL: "templates/menu.html"
    });

});
```

With my understanding this should inject the code from `menu.html` into the `ion-nav-view` tags in `index.html` at run-time. However, when the page is loaded, it simply displays `index.html` with no injected code. 

I have been unable to find specific instructions on each property of `state`, making a possible error in my code hard to decipher. I also have found that `state` may be deprecated by the latest version of Angular, but Ionic docs explain to use `state` so that is what I have been trying to do. Any clarification or resources would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ionic appears using [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router), you can read up on the docs there to see how that piece works.

Comment: cool, will do and see if i solve it myself. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unsure if this is even worthy of an answer, but, in case someone else has a similar issue.

Ionic uses `ui-router`, a framework that replaces ngRoute. My specific issue was that I was missing the line `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/")`, which serves as a default route. I also used the incorrect casing on `templateURL`, it was supposed to be `templateUrl`. Perhaps someone can learn from my silly mistake.